# Capturing the Click event in an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, user-interface, spreadsheet, event-driven, vba

How can I capture the event in Excel when a user clicks on a cell.  I want to be able to use this event to trigger some code to count how many times the user clicks on several different cells in a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Worksheet_SelectionChange event. In that event you could use Intersect() with named ranges to figure out if a specific range were clicked.

Here's some code that might help you get started.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("SomeNamedRange")) Is Nothing Then
         'Your counting code 
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Worksheet.SelectionChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.selectionchange(VS.80).aspx) event to trap this.

Answer (score 0):

Worksheet SelectionChange event would do it. Note that this fires **every** time user clicks a new cell.